# How to write a function to count how many times a character occurs in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

This is what I have so far:

```
def count2(char,text):
    if len(text)==0:
        return 0
    else:
        if char==count2(char,text[:-1]):
            return (1+count2(char,text[:-1]))
        else:
            return False
```

It will just go to false, but I am trying to count how many times "char" equals each character of "text."

Comment: Why are you returning false from your counting method? false isn't a count of anything

Comment: Why compare `char` (a `str`) with the return value of `count2` (an `int` or a `bool`)?

Comment: This is not an inherently recursive problem (although it can be solved recursively).  Is the recursive part a stated requirement of the problem?

Comment: `'engineers'.count('e')` returns `3`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base case looks correct. For your recursive case, lets take a look at the logic. There are two possible cases:

1. If the first character of the current string is the one you are looking for. In this case, you should return 1 + the count of the character in the rest of the string.
2. If the first character is not equal, then you should just return the count of the character in the rest of the string.

The function thus becomes

```
def count2(char,text):
    if len(text)== 0:
        return 0
    count = 1 if text[0] == char else 0
    return count + count2(char, text[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to achieve this will be using [`string.count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) function as:

```
>>> 'engineering'.count('e')
3
```

But I believe it is the part of some assignment. Since you are specific for using *recursive* function, below is the sample code to  achieve this as:

```
def numberofcharacters(my_char, my_string):
    if my_string:
       if my_char == my_string[0]:
            return 1 + numberofcharacters(my_char, my_string[1:])
       else:
            return numberofcharacters(my_char, my_string[1:])
    else:
       return 0
```

This solution can be further simplified as:

```
def numberofcharacters(my_char, my_string):
    return ((my_char == my_string[0]) + numberofcharacters(my_char, my_string[1:])) if my_string else 0
```

Sample run:

```
>>> numberofcharacters('e','engineering')
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has a neat way of treating True/False as 1/0, so you could simply write something like this:

```
def numberofcharacters(char, text):
    if len(text) == 0:
        return 0
    return (text[-1] == char) + numberofcharacters(char, text[:-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 def count2(char, text):
    charCount = 0
    for i in text:
        if i == char:
            charCount += 1
    return(charCount)
```

Here's my two sense on the matter, a less complicated solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension makes things clear :

```
def numberofcharacters(my_char, my_string):
    return len([c for c in my_string if c == my_char])
```