# Converting a iteration into recursion

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

I'm trying to learn python recursion, and trying to code the following question with just recursion:
Given a string and a character, return the number of times the character is shown in the string.
Ex: 'p', 'Apple' should return 2

Here is my code below:

```
def count(char,text):
    total=0
    if char==text[0]:
        total+=1
        if len(text)==1:
            print( total)
        else:
            return count(char,text[1:])
    else:
        return count(char,text[1:])
```

I think what is really messing me up is the variable total always being reset to 0 on each recursion. In addition, I'm not totally confident in my base case. How can I fix this?

Comment: `return 0 if text == '' else (1 if char == text[0] else 0) + count(char, text[1:])`

Comment: Related: [How to write a function to count how many times a character occurs in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40197391/how-to-write-a-function-to-count-how-many-times-a-character-occurs-in-a-string/40197516#40197516)

Comment: how can I directly edit my code to make it work? mine doesn't seem to be that far off

Comment: All you would need to change in your code would be to take total an arg and add a base case where `if not text:return total` first, removing the, that would still leave redundant code but would give the correct output

Comment: @PadraicCunningham what if we aren't allowed to take any other arguments

Comment: I've edited my solution, but still to no avail. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code? I wasn't really looking for a new solution

Comment: I rolled back edits to this question, because this is a **question and answer site, not a discussion forum**. Questions need to reflect the **question** that is to be answered, and should not be edited to show an answer. Answers go in the answer section. This is vital so that people who pass by later can properly understand what the question was.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you could do it, though it's a bit memory inefficient because it has to create a new string for every recursive call.

```
def count(char, text):
    if not text:
        return 0
    return (1 if text[0] == char else 0) + count(char, text[1:])
```

You could improve the memory efficiency a bit by passing an index along so that it can reuse the same string and doesn't have to create a new one each time.

```
def count(char, text, i=0)
    if i >= len(text):
        return 0
    return (1 if text[i] == char else 0) + count(char, text, i + 1)
```

To explain some of the syntax to those that may not be familiar with it, this is the python [*ternary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) operator

```
1 if text[i] == char else 0
```

Functionally, its the same as

```
if text[i] == char:
    return 1
else:
    return 0
```

It's just shorter and still easy to read.

Comment: Since `bool` is a subclass of `int`, you can simply write `return (text[i] == char) + count(char, text, i+1)`.

Comment: I'm not quite familar with this syntax of  return (1 if text[0] == char else 0) + count(char, text[1:])

Comment: @user7061872 It's Python's conditional expression: `a if b else c` evaluates to `b` if `a` is true, `c` otherwise.

Comment: Thank you Brendan! Could you direct me more specifically as how I can edit my initial code. The only thing that is throwing it off is the total variable

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this is putting an iterator  in the method head to go through each character (you don't even need a total variable in this case):

```
def count(char, text, spot)
    if spot >= len(text):
        return 0
    if text[spot] == char:
        return 1 + count(char, text, spot + 1)
    return count(char, text, spot + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is nearly identical to Brenden Abel's answer, but you can simplify the recursive part by making it a closure over the character to count and the string to search:

```
def count(char, text):
    def count_helper(index):
        return 0 if index < 0 else (text[index] == char) + count_helper(index-1)
    return count_helper(len(text)-1)
```

(And by "simplify", I just mean reduce the number of arguments from 3 to 1.)